# Writing into Excel by using Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm very new to programming and I'm just starting out to try. So sorry if my question comes off as too basic. I'm currently trying to extract columns of data from 1 excel sheet to be written into an output excel sheet. However, after I have extracted the column, I am unable to write it into my output sheet as I get the error:
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_excel'`

Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

#Read data from input excel
sourcepath = pd.read_excel("path to input excel",indexcol=0)

#extract data from input excel
col1 = list(sourcepath.iloc[1:345,0])
col1 = [str(x)for x in col1]

#write data into output excel
extractpath = "path to output excel"
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(extractpath,engine='xlsxwriter')
col1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=True)

writer.save()
```

I'm also not sure if the line `col1 = [Str(x) for x in col1]`is even required at all for this code? I copied it off the net and not really sure the use of this.

Thank you very much for your help! Greatly appreciated <3

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The error is telling you that you cannot write a list to excel, which is what you are doing by trying to write `col1`. What you write to excel is a pandas dataframe. If you only want to write  one column the construct would be `sourcepath['col1'].to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was cast to a list.

```
col1 = list(sourcepath.iloc[1:345,0])
```

Create a new dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(col1)
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=True)
```